# printing objects onto view from axios get request on reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently trying to print values from objects from the response data I am getting back from axios get API on reactjs.

I currently have 7 objects with value arrays inside all of them coming back on the DOM via console.log. I've tried to use the .map function to print values from the objects but keep getting undefined error or this.state.thisData.map is not a function.

Any recommendations on how to print various values from different objects?

```
module.exports = class ViewConsultTest extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);


        this.state = {
            consultData: []

        }
    }


  componentDidMount() {
    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest =
       axios.get('/api/Consults/viewConsultData')
        .then(function(results){
          console.log(results.data);
          _this.setState({
            consultData: results.data
          });
         })
  }



  render () {
    return(
        <div>
          <h3>Returning Users:</h3>
            {this.state.consultData.consultNotes.map(function(consult) {
          return (
            <div>{consult.noteText}</div>
          );
         })}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[screenshot of the objects i am trying to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTKKI.png)

Comment: can u share the code? are you sure if you are type of this.state.thisData is an array.?

Comment: updated the question with the code

Comment: What does one consult object in the consultNotes look like?

Comment: consultNotes
:
Array(1)
0
:
consultId
:
1
createdAt
:
"2017-09-28T14:38:32.000Z"
createdBy
:
null
id
:
1
noteText
:
"hello dolly"
updatedAt
:
"2017-09-28T15:03:31.000Z"
updatedBy
:
null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the render method as,
because initially you are not getting data and render method is breaking its flow.

```
render () {
    var consultNotes= this.state.consultData.consultNotes;
    consultNotes = consultNotes ? consultNotes : [];
    return(
        <div>
          <h3>Returning Users:</h3>
            {consultNotes.map(function(consult) {
          return (
            <div>{consult.noteText}</div>
          );
         })}
        </div>
  );
 }
```

Comment: still not printing anything, but there is no 'undefined' error. I am updating my question with a screenshot of what the objects look like on my dom if that helps

Comment: it means you are not getting anything. print console.log(this.state.consultData);  and let me know

Comment: console log is returning everything in the dom, it just doesn't seem to print onto my view.

Comment: can u check dom via inspect element? check if it is added in html?

Comment: html under the 'returning users' is empty

Comment: What is value of consultNotes in second line of render?

Comment: consultNotes
:
Array(1)
0
:
consultId
:
1
createdAt
:
"2017-09-28T14:38:32.000Z"
createdBy
:
null
id
:
1
noteText
:
"hello dolly"
updatedAt
:
"2017-09-28T15:03:31.000Z"
updatedBy
:
null

Comment: What is type of(consultNotes[0])?

Comment: the typeof array is an object

Comment: Type of what? Array or consultNotes[0]

Comment: the typeof consultNotes[0]  should return a string

Comment: If type of consultNotes[0] is string it won’t work. It must be object

Comment: figured it out, i was forgetting to call objects in the setState. accepting your answer since it was my own fault